# How to get free mongoDB connection string?

Tags: mongodb, connection-string

While connecting to the server we need mongoDB connection string which was free earlier now its paid. Is there any other way to get the same for free

procedure to get the free connection string

Comment: Hope you need to ask how to get free mongo database.

Answer (score 1):

Try this url that you can find forever free MongoDB.

https://www.mongodb.com/pricing

otherwise you can install your own MongoDB on your machine or server.

Answer (score 0):

Go to MongoDB and create a project. After creating a deployment you'll be directed to a page like the one in the image. Select FREE[image: image of MongoDB pricing]

Follow the subsequent steps then connect to cluster. Once you choose a connection method, a connection string will be provided.